# RSpec update_attributes expectation failing, even though update works

Tags: rspec, expectations

I'm using what is largely a scaffold generated RSpec spec, which is failing but shouldn't be.  Here is the spec:

```
describe "PUT update" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested invoice" do


      invoice = Invoice.create!

       Invoice.any_instance.should_receive(:update_attributes).with({"number" => "MyString"  })
    put :update, {:id => invoice.id, :invoice => { "number" => "MyString" }}
  end
```

When the spec is run, one Invoice is created in the db, and is updated appropriately.  However, I get this message and a fail:

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (#<Mocha::ClassMethods::AnyInstance:0x653a9a8>).update_attributes({"number"=>"MyString"})
expected: 1 time with arguments: ({"number"=>"MyString"})
received: 0 times with arguments: ({"number"=>"MyString"})
```

Why is this failing?

Comment: Are you using both `RSpec::Mocks` and `Mocha`?

Comment: The Mocha gem is installed.

Comment: Assuming you _want_ to be using Mocha with RSpec, did you follow the insructions at https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/mock-framework-integration/mock-with-mocha?

Comment: Actually, the installed Mocha gem is a holdover from when I was first setting up the project and hadn't decided to use RSpec (as opposed to minutest which is what I've used in the past).  RSpec is not configured to use mocha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, since your getting a Mocha error, it seems to me you need to either disable Mocha or configure it for use with RSpec.

You can disable a gem by removing it from Gemfile and re-executing `bundle install`. Or you can add a 'require: false` argument when specifying the gem so that it doesn't autoload, per [Bundler: What does :require => false in a Gemfile mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800721/bundler-what-is-the-require-false-on-the-gemfile-means)

Instructions for configuring Mocha to work with RSpec are in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/mock-framework-integration/mock-with-mocha

Comment: The obvious is frequently the answer.  That was, in fact, the problem.  I should have picked up on that.  I'm unclear as to why Mocha was involving itself as RSpec was supposed to use it's own mocking facilities.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by using expects instead of should_receive. You might just need to update it to use expects like the following.

```
describe "PUT update" do
  describe "with valid params" do
    it "updates the requested invoice" do
      invoice = Invoice.create!
      Invoice.any_instance.expects(:update_attributes).with({"number" => "MyString"  })
      put :update, {:id => invoice.id, :invoice => { "number" => "MyString" }}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Mocha, like many other mock frameworks, requires you to put your expectations before running the code under test.

Therefore, in your test, swap the two lines; i.e. call `Invoice.create!` **after** `Invoice.any_instance.should_receive`.

Comment: The update attributes innovation is already occurring after the expeditions are set, in the line that follows.