# When do you need a require in a rails Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile

In my gemfile I have things like:

```
gem 'net-sftp', '2.1.1', :require => 'net/sftp'
gem 'backup', '3.0.27'
gem 'watu_table_builder', :require => 'table_builder'
gem 'browser', '0.1.6'
```

When in a Gemfile do you need a require? I've also found things like `:require => false`. Help?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800721/bundler-what-is-the-require-false-on-the-gemfile-means

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you omit the `:require` option, by default Bundler will attempt to require the gem by using the standard name-to-file conversion rule:

> dashes are considered namespace separators and underscore classname separators

It means that the following gem statements

```
gem 'net-sftp'
gem 'backup'
gem 'foo_bar'
```

are equivalent to

```
gem 'net-sftp', require: 'net/sftp'
gem 'backup', require: 'backup'
gem 'foo_bar', require: 'foo_bar'
```

This works well if the gem author has followed the standard conventions. But in some cases, for a variety of reasons, this doesn't happen.

For instance, there are gems called `foo-bar` where the main filename is `/foo_bar.rb` or even `/foo.rb`. In this case you provide the `:require` option to tell Bundler which file you want to require.

Finally, `require: false` is used when you want a gem to be part of the bundle, but you don't want Bundler to load it by default.

This is useful, for instance, to lazy-load a gem in case it is used only in certain circumstances. Think about a rake task that includes a heavy gem. You don't want your application to load it on boot, but it needs to be part of the bundle or it will not be found.

In this case you pass the option `require: false`. Then, in your rake task you will require it manually as usual

```
require 'library'
```

The library will be loaded only when the task is invoked, not in the normal application execution.

A good example is [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever). The library must be part of the bundler because it must be bundled when you deploy the app, but it is intended to be run as a command line script. For this reason, you don't want Bundler to require it when the Rails application is started.

There are cases where you use groups instead of `require: false`.

See also the [official Bundler documentation for `require`](http://bundler.io/v1.5/man/gemfile.5.html#REQUIRE-AS-require-).

Comment: Thank you! This is a great, detailed answer. Very much appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `:require` if the name of the file that's required to activate the gem can't be inferred from the gem's name. Ruby convention is to [name your gem the same thing as the "require" statement you should use](http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/), but not everything follows the convention.

`:require => false` disables automatic requiring by Bundler, so you'd need to use `require 'foo'` manually to use the code in `foo`. This is mainly useful if a gem is large or expensive to activate and only used in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is often used if the name of the library to require is different than the name of the gem. In your case it would download the `gem 'watu_table_builder'`, but would call `'table_builder'`.

Answer (score 0):

`require` specifies other files that would be required on requiring this particular gem.

Documentation says

> Each gem MAY specify files that should be used when autorequiring via
>   Bundler.require. You may pass an array with multiple files, or false
>   to prevent any file from being autorequired.

Refer to [this](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html#REQUIRE-AS-require) for whole documentation