# Gem needs to be required manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've created a gem. You can see the full source code here:
https://github.com/agilie/instagram_api_gem (in any case, not advertising)

However, when I use it in the Rails project

```
# Gemfile
gem 'instagram_api_client'
```

it doesn't work untill a manually  require it somewhere in the initializers like

```
require 'instagram_api'
```

**Why does this happen?** I want it to work without any manual requires like other rails gems work.

Comment: Where this gem is located? Have you uploaded it to rubygems? Have you re-run `bundle` after you have the gem added to it?

Comment: Yes, it is on rubygems (https://rubygems.org/gems/instagram_api_client). I've tried both ways - from rubygems and directly from repository. The result is the same. Sure I did bundle after adding.

Comment: You should follow RubyGems' naming conventions. From the [make your own gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) guide: _"Code for your package is placed within the **lib** directory. The convention is to have **one** Ruby file with the **same name** as your gem, since that gets loaded [...]"_

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems I've missed this recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not conform Rails autoloading rules. Create a file `instagram_api_client.rb` with a content

```
require 'instagram_api'
```

in the top level of `lib` folder. That should do the trick.

For gems, the name of the file to be loaded automatically should be exactly equal to the name of the gem.

---

Or, as suggested by @TomLord, one might simply specify

```
gem 'instagram_api_client', require: 'instagram_api'
```

in the `Gemfile` itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll give it a try

Comment: You don't need a top-level `lib` folder. You can specify `require: "..."` *in the Gemfile*.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant, @mudasobwa -- For example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21029195/1954610

Comment: @TomLord oh, indeed. Need more ☕. Thanks, updated. The preferrable way, still, would be not to enforce all users of your gem to apply `require` explicitly.