# Error using --watch . in SASS

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I have used SASS alot and I never had an error or problem with it. But today I tried to watch my css folder this error came up. I tried to solve it by google/search on Stack overflow but coulden´t find any good answer.

> sass --watch.
>
> ```
> C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not
> find 'sass' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
> from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec
> '
> from C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in
> `gem'
> from C:/Ruby193/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278047/could-not-find-rails-0-amongst-gemloaderror or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152553/rails-could-not-find-gem-sdoc-0-ruby

Comment: That did not help me, Im not that familiar with either ruby or linux.