# Sinatra launches after rails console exits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, jruby, rack, rails-console

**Sinatra** launches immediately after exiting **rails-console**:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.11)
[1] pry(main)> exit
[2014-02-06 14:01:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-02-06 14:01:50] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-01-09) [java]
== Sinatra/1.3.3 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2014-02-06 14:01:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4516 port=4567
```

The problem occurs when **irb** is used as the **rails-console** repl as well.

The problem does not occur when rails exits, only when rails console exits.

The problem occurs using **jruby-1.7.10** but *not* **jruby-1.6.7**.  The problem was originally noticed after upgrading.

**Sinatra** is available elsewhere in my stack (so it starting is not completely out of left field) but why does it start when **rails-console** exits.

A temporary fix to this is the following steps:

1. remove `gem 'sinatra'` from the `Gemfile`
2. run `$ bundle install`
3. add `gem 'sinatra'` back to the `Gemfile`
4. run `$ bundle install`

Unfortunately, after a few modifications to the to Gemfile and another `bundle install` the issue persists.  I imagine this a bug in bundler, but of all things to happen why would a sintra server launch?

Comment: It's not a bug it's a feature!

Comment: @diego.greyrobot how do I disable that feature?

Comment: Ok all joking aside, I have no idea. I'd say you have some line of code somewhere that is causing this. Maybe in a *rc file or a rake file. By *rc file I mean something like .irbrc etc. Also, try searching your project directory for that line of code, there's only a few ways to launch the sinatra process i.e. calling ruby my_sinatra_file.rb. Figure out which file it is first and then grep for that line in your project.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. We solved it by changing our `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem 'sinatra', require: false
```

More info about what this does can be found in: 
[Bundler: What does :require => false in a Gemfile mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800721/bundler-what-does-require-false-in-a-gemfile-mean)