# Using "require 'my_module'" in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Still learning RoR, sometimes I'll see an example use of a library in plain Ruby that has `require 'my_library'`.

When we're in Ruby on Rails, are we able to do `require`? Or does everything have to be included in the gemfile (which I guess both installs and requires the library).

In particular I'm trying to call a API:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :other_models

    def get_score
       require 'rest_client'
       response = RestClient.post 'https://sender.blockspring.com/api/blocks/da289f59df228ac4e89cebdfc9aa41fd?api_key=fe5cf0d86af27c086ab5cd4d0eab6641', { items_as_json_string: '[{"time_since_post_in_hours": 5, "upvote_count": 22}, {"time_since_post_in_hours": 3, "upvote_count": 502}]' }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can require things, but you generally don't need to when they are declared in the Gemfile.  One particular case where you'd need to require them [is if you told it so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800721/bundler-what-is-the-require-false-on-the-gemfile-means), such as (in your `Gemfile`):

```
gem 'something_very_specific', require: false
```

Now, you'll need to require it in the "very specific" place you intended to use it.

Answer (score 1):

`require` is part of *Ruby* and not unique to *Rails*. You can `require` stuff in *Rails* and it is normally done at the top of the **Class** and not inside of methods. `require` simply runs the file to make sure the functionality you are trying to use is loaded.