# Ignore group in Rails Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, mailcatcher

I have the `puma` gem in my Rails 4.1.8 Gemfile because I want to use it as the default webserver in all environments. That works fine.

```
# Gemfile
gem "puma"
```

In development I am using `mailcatcher` which means that I'd like to include it as a dependency in my Gemfile.

```
# Gemfile
group :development do
  gem "mailcatcher"
end
```

This causes the default webserver to be set to `thin`. This appears to be an unintended consequence of mailcatcher, but it brings up a specific question. **Can I create a group that bundler obeys to install Gems, but that Rails ignores?** I tried something like this but Rails is still loading the contained gems.

```
# Gemfile
group :mailcatcher do
  gem "mailcatcher"
end
```

Comment: [“Please don't put mailcatcher into your Gemfile. It will conflict with your applications gems at some point.”](http://mailcatcher.me/) I guess this is the type of thing they mean.

Comment: Yup your application doesn't depend on it, even in development, so why shoehorn it into your application's Gemfile?  `gem install mailcatcher`, done.  Odds are there are other tools you use during development that are more involved to install, but since they aren't Ruby gems they obviously don't go in the Gemfile, this is the same thing.

Comment: Fair enough. I just don't like the fact that I have to remember to manually install Gems when I spin up a new development environment.

Comment: It just seems like there should be a way to use the Gemfile to install Gems but have Rails ignore them. Maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias `rails s` command... For example `export alias rs="rails server puma"` and now `rs` will start `puma`. This way you are free to use any webserver you want )
If you want to make it really default you can add something like this

```
require 'rack/handler'
Rack::Handler::WEBrick = Rack::Handler.get(:puma)
```

to the `rails` script.

Comment: That might work, but my question is really about having a Gem in my Gemfile that Rails doesn't load. I'm probably on the wrong track with that though. I removed `mailcatcher` from my Gemfile as the docs advised.

Comment: That will be strange - to have gem to not have it ))
So... I'm not sure you can do this. You can add gem without require it... Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work or not, but what about:

```
gem "mailcatcher", :require => false
```

Ref: [Bundler: What does :require => false in a Gemfile mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800721/bundler-what-does-require-false-in-a-gemfile-mean)

Comment: From the description it sound like exactly what I'm looking for, but it doesn't render the result I want. Rails still seems to require the gems with `:require` set to `false`.

Comment: sounds like mailcatcher just doesn't play nice.   Have you considered https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener ?

Comment: I'm just going to add a rake task that installs the other Gems required by `Mailcatcher`. If I find a better solution I'll update my question.

Comment: dumb question, but did you run bundle install after setting require false?

Answer (score 0):

Mailcatcher [specifically states to not put it in your Gemfile](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher#bundler).

> Please don't put mailcatcher into your Gemfile. It will conflict with your applications gems at some point.
>
> Instead, pop a note in your README stating you use mailcatcher. Simply run gem install mailcatcher then mailcatcher to get started.