# Ruby on Rails: where to put the 'require' files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, require

I'm trying to use this `gem barometer` and in the [document](https://github.com/attack/barometer) it says that it can be used right out of the box with using `require 'barometer'`

I've always used gems and put them in the `gemfile`, but I think this is different...

Do I just download this entire repo, and copy all the files in the `lib` folder into my `vendor` folder? or maybe `public` folder?

Where would you typically put these files? And where would you include the `require`? Should this be in the **application controller**? Or maybe in the helper? Sorry for this really noob question.

I know in my local environment, I can just type in `gem install barometer` in my console, and not have to put in a `require`, but I don't think this will work in heroku, or production environment.

Comment: put it in Gemfile. "require" might not be necessary at all (they often include that in doco in case you are using plain ruby)... if it doesn't Just Work, than add your require to your application.rb (not your controller), in `config/application.rb`

Comment: Heroku bundle-installs the gems based on the Gemfile. You can review the Heroku build log in the console (after you have run git push).

Comment: @TarynEast if not in controller, but Gareth, mentioned it can be?

Comment: Ye s"it can"... but generally that kind of thing clutters up your controller/model etc. Generally requires go all in the one place. Often you don't even need them with a gem (you just put it in your Gemfile... and Gemfile requires it for you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800721/bundler-what-does-require-false-in-a-gemfile-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've always used gems and put them in the gemfile, but I think this is different...

No, this is no different. Barometer is a [Rubygem](https://rubygems.org/gems/barometer) and putting it in your Gemfile is exactly the way to use it.

As with every library, your require should go in whichever file uses the code, for example the same file that the `Barometer.new` call is. You don't always *need* the `require` line depending on your Ruby environment, but it's always a good idea to get used to it

Comment: But would I put it in a view.html.erb file? Or would it be better if I call it through the `model.rb`? Or it doesn't matter? Just as long as wherever the `Barometer.new` would be called would be okay? Just trying to figure out best practice purposes

Comment: You probably don't want to doing anything that makes network calls in your views. If the barometer code relates to a specific model then you should probably put the code in there, otherwise it should be in your controller - or if that comes to more than a few lines of code, in another module which is *called* by your controller

Comment: Cool, makes sense. Thanks for your help!