# Conditionally setting require: true in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

I'd like to conditionally set `require:` in my Gemfile definition depending on the environment to work in conjunction with `Bundler.require`. E.g. i'd like pry to be available in all environments but only have `require: true` set in development and test. I'm currently doing something like this:

```
# make pry available for anyone who wants it
# but not automatically required
# e.g. in a console
gem 'pry', require: false

# automatically require pry
# for easy usage in tests
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry', require: true
end
```

Which works but results in a nice warning regarding a duplicate gem definition:

> Your Gemfile lists the gem pry (>= 0) more than once.
>   You should probably keep only one of them.
>   While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.

Alternately, I can try to do something like this:

```
gem 'pry', require: ENV["RACK_ENV"] != "production"
```

but that feels much less declarative (and a little gross).

### Edit:

To clarify,

1. I want to be to have pry available via `Bundler.require` in the development and test environments
2. Be available in production (e.g. for use in a console) without being automatically required via `Bundler.require`

Comment: `require: true` is not a valid option. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800721/bundler-what-does-require-false-in-a-gemfile-mean for an explanation of what the `require` option does.

Comment: I think it is valid according to https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/2538 (it's just an alias) although perhaps it has been removed in later versions of bundler?

Comment: Ah. It makes sense to `require: someboolean` that can be `true` or `false`, but to use `require: true` with the literal `true` is redundant. `gem 'pry'` and `gem 'pry', require: true` are both equivalent to `gem 'pry', require: 'pry'`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `:require => false` when you want the gem to be installed but not "required". If you are not planning to use 'pry' gem in production it doesn't make sense to even install it in production.

You can make a gem available to use in any environment by explicitly specifying it.
E.g. Make pry available in development and test environments

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
end
```

Hope, this helps!

Comment: I am actually planning to use pry in production for a poor man's console so I want to have it available for a console script but not automatically required when my Sinatra application initialized

Comment: Interesting! In that case just add `gem 'pry', :require => false` to your Gemfile.

Also you will need to add `require 'pry' if (Bundler.definition.groups & [:development, :test]).any?` to your application.rb or app.rb or whatever.

Good Luck!

Comment: If I set `require => false` in my Gemfile pry won't be available in my tests without explicitly `require`ing it though right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct! And that is why you will need to add `require 'pry' if (Bundler.definition.groups & [:development, :test]).any?` to your application.rb

Answer (score 1):

Grouping your dependencies allows you to perform operations on the entire group.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry', require: true
end
```

The above code itself says `pry gem` will be required in `development` and `test` environment only. Not in production. So you don't need to specify that it should not required in production.

If you mention `gem 'pry'` in your gem file without specifying anything then it will be required in all environment default.

For more information kindly refer this link : http://bundler.io/groups.html

---

From : **[The How and Why of Bundler Groups](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/)**

> Specifying groups allows you to do two things. First, you can install
>   the gems in your Gemfile, minus specific groups. For instance, Rails
>   puts mysql and pg in a database group so that if you’re just working
>   on ActionPack, you can bundle install --without db and run the
>   ActionPack tests without having to worry about getting the gems
>   installed.
>
> Second, you can list specific groups to autorequire using
>   Bundler.require. By default, Bundler.require requires all the gems in
>   the default group (which is all the gems that have no explicit group).
>   You can also say Bundler.require(:default, :another_group) to require
>   specific groups.

Comment: I just made an edit, the issue is I want it available in all environments, but not required in production.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the group name in your `Bundler.require` then the gems are loaded as well (except those that explicitly indicate `require: false`).

For example having a Gemfile with the following content:

```
gem 'redis'

group :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end
```

If you do `Bundler.require` it will only require `redis` **and** if you do `Bundler.require(:default, :test)` it will require both `pry` and `redis`; notice that still `simplecov` won't be required even if you explicitly indicate the `:test` group. So to use `simplecov` you will still need to explicitly call `require 'simplecov'`