# Does require: false in Gemfile make better performance when gem is required in app folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example:

In my Gemfile there are two gems:

`gem 'spreadsheet', require: false`

`gem 'stripe', require: false`

I use `'spreadsheet'` in rake tasks and it's clear that `require: false` makes better performance.

But my rails app also uses `'stripe'` for payment in app folder(models,controllers..etc) which is not often executed. (On production server, with `config.eager_load = true` )

Will the performance be better to set `require: false` for  `gem 'stripe'` ?

I've read straight through this question but can't get clear answer： [Bundler: What does :require => false in a Gemfile mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800721)

Answer (score 1):

You'll get some improvements in application start-up time - gems that have `require: false` are not loaded when application starts. This can also help in test mode - see https://www.andywaite.com/2015/08/15/faster-tdd-in-rails-with-bundlers-require-false.html. Also, if you only need those gems in rake tasks, or one-off scripts, the main application will use less memory, which is always a nice bonus.