# Bundler cannot find `whenever` gem, when deploying using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I am trying to deploy my app in a staging environment using Capistrano.

Running `cap staging deploy` results in error saying:

```
bundler: failed to load command: whenever (/home/ubuntu/builder/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/whenever)

 DEBUG [52d26072]   Gem::Exception: can't find executable whenever for gem whenever. whenever is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?
```

I have already included `whenever` gem in the local Gemfile but still it is not able to find it:
Here's a part of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'capistrano', 
gem 'capistrano-secrets-yml'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-rails'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

I am not able to find what the problem is. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would try `bundle exec cap staging deploy` to make sure you are executing the command using your bundle. Additionally you may need to remove `require => false` because [it does not include the library when you load your bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4800746/2149359).